# The output of my code comes out too slowly.. How can i speed up my process

Tags: python-3.x

Thanks to the help from some users of this sites.

My code seems to work fine, but it's taking too long..

I'm trying to compare two data frames.(`df1` has 1,291,250 rows / `df2` has 1,286,692 rows)

if `df1.iloc[0,0] == df2.iloc[0,0]` and `df1.iloc[0,1] == df2.iloc[0,1]`, then compare `df1.iloc[0,2]`, `df2.iloc[0,2]`.

If the first(`df1.iloc[0,2]`) is larger, I want to put the **first index** into the list, and if the second(`df2.iloc[0,2]`) is larger, I want to put the **second index** into the list.

#### Example DataFrame

```c
In [1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 98], [1, 1, 198], [2, 2, 228]], columns = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'])
In [2]: df1
Out[3]:
         A1  B1   C1
      0   0   1   98
      1   1   1  198
      2   2   2  228

In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 228], [1, 2, 110], [2, 2, 130]], columns = ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'])
In [5]: df2
Out[6]:
         A2  B2   C2
      0   0   1  228
      1   1   2  110
      2   2   2  130

In [7]: def find_high(df1, df2) # def function code is below
Out[8]: ([2], [0])  # The result what i want
```

**This is just simple example. my data is bigger than this**

#### my code is:

```c
for i in range(60):
    setattr(mod, f'df_1_{i}', np.array_split(df1, 60)[i])
    getattr(mod, f'df_1_{i}').to_pickle(f'df_1_{i}')


import glob
files = glob.glob('df_1_*')


def find_high_pre(df1 = files, df2):
    subtract_df2 = []
    subtract_df1 = []
    same_data = []
    for df1_index, line in enumerate(df1.to_numpy()):
        for df2_idx, row in enumerate(df2.to_numpy()):
            if (line[0:2] == row[0:2]).all():
                if line[2] < row[2]:
                    subtract_df2.append(df2_idx)
                    break
                elif line[2] > row[2]:
                    subtract_df1.append(df1_idx)
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break

    return df1.iloc[subtract_df1].index.tolist(), df2.iloc[subtract_df2].index.tolist(), df1.iloc[same_data].index.to_list();

data_1 = []
for i in files:
    e_data = pd.read_pickle(i)
    num_cores = 30
    df_split = np.array_split(e_data, num_cores)
    data_1 += parmap.map(find_high_pre, df_split, pm_pbar=True, pm_processes =num_cores)
```

Comment: "slow" you are using nested  for loop that means `1,291,250 * 1,286,692`

Comment: Showing examples of your dfs and expected output using small cases would make it easier to answer. See [how to make good reprexes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

> My code seems to work fine, but it's taking too long..

Chances are that replacing your nested `for` loops with a [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operation will take less time:

```
keys = ['A', 'B']
df1.columns = [*keys, 'C1']
df2.columns = [*keys, 'C2']
df = df1.reset_index().set_index(keys).merge(
     df2.reset_index().set_index(keys), on=keys)
# now we have a merged dataframe like this:
#      index_x   C1  index_y   C2
# A B                            
# 0 1        0   98        0  228
# 2 2        2  228        2  130
# therefrom we can easily extract the wanted indexes
data = [df.loc[df['C1'] > df['C2'], 'index_x'].values,
        df.loc[df['C1'] < df['C2'], 'index_y'].values]
```

Comment: oh!!  thank you for telling me a good way. Now i can reduce nested for loop.